# Custom entity matching issues

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a custom entity for specific gravity and if a user enters in 1.042, 1.043 something exact it will not match the reference value. However if they are using the other synonyms work fine.

Custom Entity
[1.042 is the reference synonyms are: 10 42, 1042, 1 dot 042, 1 point 042, 1.042](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm7yP.png)

Intent
[calculate abv 1.080 to 1.010 (numbers mapping to custom entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAgIi.png)

Comment: Which data type are you using?

Comment: I'm not positive which data type you are specifying. It is a custom entity the values are above and that is what the intent is matching. It matches fine on voice but if a user inputs the exact number it thinks it is not a match. 

I didn't see a spot to specify data type either in the entity itself or the intent since it is matching the custom entity.

Comment: I deleted the entity and created a new one and went on to simplify it and matched the number 1.042 to the synonyms: 1.042, 10 42, 1042 and it seems to be working fine now ‍♂️